# Doing file syncronization between local folder and Azure BlobContainer, etag, modified since ect

Tags: azure

I am working on syncing a file from local storage to a Azure blob Storage. I failed to find some information, other then the default information about the properties on MSDN Documentation site.

I have previously used the eTag property to see if a file have changed for syncing down to my local machine. (We are only talking about one way sync). Are there any documentation about what the etag property is? is it a file MD5 hash or somthing else.

I seen another implementation that keeps md5 hash of the file in memory for local files and stores its on the files meta data on the container, and wondering if thats the way to go?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The approach you are using with the Etag is the most common that I've seen. The Etag is changed when the blob changes ... however - it won't tell you if that change really didn't change anything (where the MD5 hash would).

For example:

If you upload an image, then put another image in place of the first one.  Both the Etag and the MD5 would be different.  But if you now change that image back to the first one, the Etag again will be different but the MD5 would be the same as the first one you had.

Comment: But without the MD5 hash, would i then be able to detect what files have changed since last sync? if i do not store the servers etag alongside the files? Guess I am asking if I can  calculate the etag on local files?

Comment: Good point, you won't be able to 'calculate' the etag.  If you want to check for a change you would be most accurate to store the md5 on the metadata of the blob and then compare the local file's md5 (after calculating it or pulling from local storage).

Comment: The md5 is calculated automatic on every upload with the 2.0 storage client, works nicely